# Is there a way to disable R abbreviation in list indexing?

Tags: r, list, null, abbreviation

at the moment I'm quite stunned by this piece of code:

```
bad.list <- list(xx = "A")
print(is.null(bad.list$x))   # FALSE: Bad since there is no x
print(is.null(bad.list$xx))  # FALSE: Correct since there is xx
print(is.null(bad.list$xxx)) # TRUE:  Correct since there is no xxx
```

Normally you would expect `is.null(bad.list$x)` to be evaluated as `TRUE` since there is no `x` in the list. But since R allows you to use abbreviations it evaluates to `FALSE`. In my situation I can't change the names of the list entries.

Is there a way to force R to disable abbreviations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `[[...]]` notation:

```r
bad.list <- list(xx = "A")
print(is.null(bad.list[["x"]]))   # is TRUE now
print(is.null(bad.list[["xx"]]))  # FALSE: Correct since there is xx
print(is.null(bad.list[["xxx"]])) # TRUE:  Correct since there is no xxx
```